# Is there any way to rollback devops pipeline on last successful?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am trying to rollback in release pipeline when the latest release gets fail it will revert at last successful. I added a PowerShell task which only runs when previous tasks have failed and script which is triggering last successful but the problem is it start redeploying stages randomly not sequentially.## Heading ##

In my scenario I have 3 stages, at the end of each stage, I have added a PowerShell task that will trigger only when the previous task has failed and wrote a script accordingly to trigger last successful release. so it will trigger all the stages in the last release because I haven't got any API or command to trigger release by id. I have an API which triggers only stages. All the stages are queueing sequentially but running randomly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zbve0.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Sudarshan Sharma. I shared a method in the release pipeline to automatically re-deploy successful stage. Please check if it could meet your requirement. If it does not work, you can share your powershell script and the problems encountered. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using the Release Pipeline, I suggest that you could use `Auto-redeploy trigger option` for each stage.

[image]

When the stage fails, it will re-deploy the last successful release of the current stage.

[image]

For example:

Set `Auto-redeploy trigger option` for stage 2 -> Stage2 fail -> Auto redeploy the last successful Stage 2

**Update:**

From you requirement, you could try to use the `Release Orchestrator`task from [Release Orchestrator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dmitryserbin.release-orchestrator&targetId=bc9ec5d1-abad-46fc-ae7d-be0753501b44) extension. This task could be used to manage the release.

Here is the example:

[image]

You could use this task to replace the powershell task. This task supports to select the re-run release name and the target stages.

It can also be sorted according to the input stage order.

[image]

**Note:** you also need to set `Maximum number of parallel deployments` as 2 for `each stage -> Pre-deployment conditions-> Deployment queue settings`.

[image]

Comment: Yes but this option is only for a particular STAGE in a release. I am trying to redeploy all the stage in a release when any stage in the new release will fail. Microsoft is not providing as such feature to redeploy any previous release.

Comment: Hi @SudarshanSharma. Please check my update. You could use the Release Orchestrator task . This task can meet your needs more conveniently (compare with powershell )

Comment: thanks, In my case Release Orchestrator is not working. but with this Maximum number of parallel deployments option, it is working perfectly